# Can anybody explain to me the following construction?

Tags: geometry

In [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1993494) the author constructed a square over a Jourdan curve $C$ as follows:

> On $C$, from the point $P$ at $t_0$ to the point $Q$ at $t=t_0+s$, we construct the
> chord, and upon the chord as a side erect a square in such a way that as $s$
> approaches zero the square is inside $C$. As $s$ increases we consider the two
> free corner points of the square, $P_c$ and $Q_c$, adjacent to $P$ and $Q$ respectively.
> As $s$ approaches $T$ the square will be outside $C$ and therefore both $P_c$ and $Q_c$
> must cross $C$ an odd number of times as $s$ varies from zero to $T$. The points
> may also touch $C$ without crossing.

Unfortunately I don't understand this construction and Can anybody explain to me that what is he said exactly?

Comment: What part do you understand, and what part don't you? The part you quote starts by explaining the construction of the square. Since I don't really know what (additional) properties the jordan curve $C$ has, I'm a little dubious whether you can always fit a small square inside $C$ for an arbitrary $P$. Since I also don't know what $T$ is, it's hard to say anything about $P_C$ and $Q_C$. Anyway about the square, if you have a chord of $C$, that chord defines two squares on either side of it. To decide which square to pick, the author says to look at small values of $s$ so that the square falls..

Comment: ...into $C$. I'm really uncertain as to whether a small chord will always define a small square in the interior of an arbitrary jordan curve though. Once you know what the correct square is for small $s$, I assume you deduce the square for arbitrary values by just picking the square on the same side as small values.

Comment: I really don't understand "and upon the chord as a side erect a square in such a way that as $s$ approaches zero the square is inside $C$" . the notation can be found on linked paper.

Comment: A chord is a line segment, and there are exactly two squares that admit that line segment as a side. It seems the author only wants one of the two squares, and the " as $s$ approaches zero" thing is his explanation as to which of the two squares to choose.